# No module named '' after module installed for python3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry if this is yet another "no module" question. But all previous threads didn't solve my problem.

I am using MacOs BigSur 11.6.1, and I have both python2.7 and python3.9. I noticed that using pip3, pip3.9 or homebrew sometimes don't give me the module I need when I run python3.9.

Here are my installation list. I tried uninstall and reinstall for a few times, but that might have made things even messier.

Interestingly enough, my python2.7 (/usr/bin/python) does not have this issue, although I used pip3 in (/usr/local/bin/pip3) to install them).

% which -a pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

% which -a python3.9
/usr/local/bin/python3.9

% which -a python
/usr/bin/python

which -a pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
/usr/bin/pip3

% which -a pip3.9
/usr/local/bin/pip3.9

% which -a python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3

% which brew
/usr/local/bin/brew

% which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

% which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3

Comment: Did you try `python -m pip install <package>`? If the problem is that the version of python in your path is not the one `pip` is using, that will solve it.

Comment: @baileythegreen I found a way to make this work with your hint! python3.9 -m pip install <package> works. It was one thing I didn't realize earlier.

Comment: Installing with `pip` that way specifies which python to use and runs `pip` as a module, rather than a standalone. This is probably the biggest issue people have with `pip`.